# Can I return to the Netherlands without passport (but with Dutch residence permit)?

Tags: schengen, passports, belgium, dutch-residents

I am non-EU citizen and I have a Dutch residence permit. I am planning on flying to the Barbados. I have to go to the Barbados Embassy at Brussels, Belgium, for visa application and I have to submit my passport there as part of the application.

So now I have to travel back to the Netherlands without passport but with only the residence permit. Will it be okay? Will there be any issues regarding entering back into the Netherlands?

Comment: There are no controls between Belgium and the Netherlands.

Answer (score 2):

There is no regular passport control between Belgium and the Netherlands.  However, you may be asked to show identification in either country.

In the Netherlands, a residence permit ("vreemdelingendocument") explicitly suffices: https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/paspoort-en-identiteitskaart/vraag-en-antwoord/met-welke-identiteitsbewijzen-kan-ik-mij-identificeren

I was unable to find anything enumerating the acceptable documents in Belgium, but in general a residence permit is not accepted as an identity document in countries other than the one issuing it.  In case a Belgian official is not satisfied with your Netherlands residence permit, you should be prepared to show the receipt indicating that you have left your passport at the embassy for a visa application.  This, in combination with your residence permit, ought to suffice.

Comment: I would also add to carry a copy of your passport would you - it would also help if you can get it notarized. This way, you can present it as well as your residence card.